# Determine if the following series converges or diverges. I did this...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine if this series converges or diverges. Explain why it
> converges or diverges:
>
> 1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( 2^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \right )$
> 2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5^{n}-2^{n}}{7^{n}-6^{n}}$
> 3. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( -1 \right )^{n} \cos({\frac{\pi}{n}})$

**What I've done in 1:**
Observe that
\begin{align*}
0<a_{n}=2^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n+1}} < 2^{\frac{1}{n}} = b_{n}
\end{align*}
So, if I prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( 2^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \right )$ converges. To see that I defined $b_{n}={2^{\frac{1}{n}}}$, and then I used the ratio test, this is:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}}=1
\end{align*}
So, I can't conclude if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n} $ converges or not, even more I can't conclude if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ converges or not. *Is there any way that I can determine it?*

**What I've done in 2:**
With a similar idea than in 1, we have that
\begin{align*}
0 < a_{n} = \frac{5^{n}-2^{n}}{7^{n}-6^{n}} < \frac{5^{n}}{7^{n}-6^{n}} = b_{n}
\end{align*}
With the same idea I used the ratio test:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{5^{n+1}}{7^{n+1}-6^{n+1}} }{\frac{5^{n}}{7^{n}-6^{n}} }=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 5\left ( \frac{7^{n}-6^{n}}{7^{n+1}-6^{n+1}} \right )=\frac{5}{7}<1
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n} $ converges $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ converges. *(Is it correct my conclusion?)*

**For 3, intuitively** I think it doesn't converges but I don't know how can I show it since most of the tests to verify if $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ converges, establishes that $a_{n}>0$. *How can I prove it converges or not?*

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that is incorrect. Maybe is because the notation: $\frac{2^{\left ( \frac{1}{n+1} \right )}}{2^{\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )}}=\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{2}}{\sqrt[n]{2}}$

Comment: Yes, I misread it or suffered a mental hiccup, I’m not sure which.

Answer (score 2):

For 1,
the partial sums are
$\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\left ( 2^{\frac{1}{n}}-2^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \right )
=2-2^{\frac{1}{m}}
\to 1
$
since
$2^{\frac{1}{m}}
\to 1
$.

Therefore the sum converges to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{a_{n}}$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to+\infty}{a_{n}}=0$. Notice that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}{|(-1)^n cos(\frac{\pi}{n})|=1}$, so the series 3 is not converges.